# Calculate the cumulative distribution function using a different model

Tags: python, cdf

How can I calculate the cumulative distribution function using a different model ?
I'm specifically referring to this function

```
from scipy.stats import norm
norm.cdf(1639651)
```

Replacing he above fucntion with another one that can genearte the N50, α = , and β for any dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your model as a class that extends stats.rv_continuous as so:

```
from scipy import stats
class deterministic_gen(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _cdf(self, x):
        return np.where(x < 0, 0., 1.)
    def _stats(self):
        return 0., 0., 0., 0.
```

I think you can define only th estats and the cdf will follow. Here is the documentation: [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#making-a-continuous-distribution-i-e-subclassing-rv-continuous)